# pytest timeout in github workflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions

I am wrote some pytest routines for a package and they are working fine locally. On every push to the repository, the tests are executed for in github's "Python Package" workflow. If you take a look at [the action history](https://github.com/DrMarc/slab/actions?query=workflow%3A%22Python%20package%22), you can see that sometimes all the tests pass, but most of the times, pytest fails for one build (we are testing for python versions 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8) with an exit code 137. I assume this happens because the script gets stuck and then github terminates the process after some time.

It appears to be completely random which build is failing but it is always caused by [this script](https://github.com/DrMarc/slab/blob/master/tests/test_filter.py) and [this script](https://github.com/DrMarc/slab/blob/master/tests/test_hrtf.py) and if I am reading the pytest out correctly, they get stuck at the same position

I'm hoping someone can explain what is happening here - why do these functions fail only occasionally? How could I proceed in debugging them?

Comment: I wonder if it may have something to do with plotting functions being used? Also generally when you write tests to be discovered by pytest, each test should contain `assert` statements to test that just 1 specific method or class.

Comment: This was my first suspicion as well - but each of the plotting routines draws an die axis of a subplot that is never shown to avoid blocking. Also if the plotting blocks the script why does that happen only sometimes?

Comment: Yeah that's very mysterious that it's not deterministic... what happens when you try to re-run failed runs in your Actions history?

Comment: Seems like they work on a rerun (at least by chance)